# extract email address from String using regex

Tags: regex, flutter, parsing, dart

I want to extract email address from the Html String. First I extract the text from html string then pass the returning string into regular expression to search for email address.

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

String _parseString(String htmlString) {
  var document = parse(htmlString);

  String parsedString = parse(document.body.text).documentElement.text;

  return parsedString;
}

String _parseEmailString(String htmlString) {
  var document = parse(htmlString);

  String parsedString = parse(document.body.text).documentElement.text;
  RegExp exp = new RegExp(
    r"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$",
    caseSensitive: false,
    multiLine: false,
  );

  Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = exp.allMatches('WS://127.0.0.1:56789');
  print("hasMatch : " + exp.firstMatch("shahryar.rsm@gmail.com").toString());
  var matches2 = "hasMatch : " + exp.stringMatch(parsedString).toString();

  return matches2;
}

class HtmlToText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String string =
        '<p style=\"text-align: center\"><strong>The CV Club</strong> is a professional writing service that specialise in tailoring CVs, cover letters and more to your desired industry/ job role.</p>\n<p style=\"text-align: center\">The internet is full of dull CV templates, all exactly the same as each other. That&#8217;s why at <strong>The CV Club</strong>, we professionally tailor your CV to be as individual as you are and not at extortionate prices!</p>\n<p style=\"text-align: center\">We offer a FREE CV review and will give you constructive feedback on your current CV!</p>\n<p>Contact us on;</p>\n<p><strong>Website: <a href=\"https://www.thecvclub.org/\">https://www.thecvclub.org/</a></strong></p>\n<p><strong>Email: thecvclub@gmail.com</strong></p>\n<p><strong>Twitter: thecvclub_</strong></p>\n<p><img data-attachment-id=\"1055\" data-permalink=\"https://soleentrepreneur.co.uk/happy-world-book-day/\" data-orig-file=\"https://i2.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Happy-World-Book-Day.png?fit=800%2C800&amp;ssl=1\" data-orig-size=\"800,800\" data-comments-opened=\"1\" data-image-meta=\"{&quot;aperture&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;credit&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;camera&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;created_timestamp&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;copyright&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;focal_length&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;iso&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;shutter_speed&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orientation&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}\" data-image-title=\"Happy World Book Day!\" data-image-description=\"\" data-medium-file=\"https://i2.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Happy-World-Book-Day.png?fit=300%2C300&amp;ssl=1\" data-large-file=\"https://i2.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Happy-World-Book-Day.png?fit=800%2C800&amp;ssl=1\" class=\"alignnone size-medium wp-image-1055 alignleft\" src=\"https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Happy-World-Book-Day-300x300.png?resize=300%2C300\" alt=\"\" width=\"300\" height=\"300\" srcset=\"https://i2.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Happy-World-Book-Day.png?resize=300%2C300&amp;ssl=1 300w, https://i2.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Happy-World-Book-Day.png?resize=80%2C80&amp;ssl=1 80w, https://i2.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Happy-World-Book-Day.png?resize=768%2C768&amp;ssl=1 768w, https://i2.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Happy-World-Book-Day.png?resize=36%2C36&amp;ssl=1 36w, https://i2.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Happy-World-Book-Day.png?resize=180%2C180&amp;ssl=1 180w, https://i2.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Happy-World-Book-Day.png?resize=705%2C705&amp;ssl=1 705w, https://i2.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Happy-World-Book-Day.png?resize=120%2C120&amp;ssl=1 120w, https://i2.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Happy-World-Book-Day.png?resize=450%2C450&amp;ssl=1 450w, https://i2.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Happy-World-Book-Day.png?resize=640%2C640&amp;ssl=1 640w, https://i2.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Happy-World-Book-Day.png?resize=50%2C50&amp;ssl=1 50w, https://i2.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Happy-World-Book-Day.png?w=800&amp;ssl=1 800w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px\" data-recalc-dims=\"1\" /> <img data-attachment-id=\"1056\" data-permalink=\"https://soleentrepreneur.co.uk/lets-celebrate/\" data-orig-file=\"https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Lets-celebrate.png?fit=800%2C800&amp;ssl=1\" data-orig-size=\"800,800\" data-comments-opened=\"1\" data-image-meta=\"{&quot;aperture&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;credit&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;camera&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;created_timestamp&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;copyright&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;focal_length&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;iso&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;shutter_speed&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orientation&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}\" data-image-title=\"Let&#8217;s celebrate\" data-image-description=\"\" data-medium-file=\"https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Lets-celebrate.png?fit=300%2C300&amp;ssl=1\" data-large-file=\"https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Lets-celebrate.png?fit=800%2C800&amp;ssl=1\" class=\"alignnone size-medium wp-image-1056 alignleft\" src=\"https://i0.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Lets-celebrate-300x300.png?resize=300%2C300\" alt=\"\" width=\"300\" height=\"300\" srcset=\"https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Lets-celebrate.png?resize=300%2C300&amp;ssl=1 300w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Lets-celebrate.png?resize=80%2C80&amp;ssl=1 80w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Lets-celebrate.png?resize=768%2C768&amp;ssl=1 768w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Lets-celebrate.png?resize=36%2C36&amp;ssl=1 36w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Lets-celebrate.png?resize=180%2C180&amp;ssl=1 180w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Lets-celebrate.png?resize=705%2C705&amp;ssl=1 705w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Lets-celebrate.png?resize=120%2C120&amp;ssl=1 120w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Lets-celebrate.png?resize=450%2C450&amp;ssl=1 450w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Lets-celebrate.png?resize=640%2C640&amp;ssl=1 640w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Lets-celebrate.png?resize=50%2C50&amp;ssl=1 50w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Lets-celebrate.png?w=800&amp;ssl=1 800w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px\" data-recalc-dims=\"1\" /> <img data-attachment-id=\"1059\" data-permalink=\"https://soleentrepreneur.co.uk/need-help-with-your-cv_/\" data-orig-file=\"https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Need-help-with-your-CV_.png?fit=800%2C800&amp;ssl=1\" data-orig-size=\"800,800\" data-comments-opened=\"1\" data-image-meta=\"{&quot;aperture&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;credit&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;camera&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;caption&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;created_timestamp&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;copyright&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;focal_length&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;iso&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;shutter_speed&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;orientation&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}\" data-image-title=\"Need help with your CV_\" data-image-description=\"\" data-medium-file=\"https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Need-help-with-your-CV_.png?fit=300%2C300&amp;ssl=1\" data-large-file=\"https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Need-help-with-your-CV_.png?fit=800%2C800&amp;ssl=1\" class=\"alignnone size-medium wp-image-1059 alignleft\" src=\"https://i0.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Need-help-with-your-CV_-300x300.png?resize=300%2C300\" alt=\"\" width=\"300\" height=\"300\" srcset=\"https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Need-help-with-your-CV_.png?resize=300%2C300&amp;ssl=1 300w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Need-help-with-your-CV_.png?resize=80%2C80&amp;ssl=1 80w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Need-help-with-your-CV_.png?resize=768%2C768&amp;ssl=1 768w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Need-help-with-your-CV_.png?resize=36%2C36&amp;ssl=1 36w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Need-help-with-your-CV_.png?resize=180%2C180&amp;ssl=1 180w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Need-help-with-your-CV_.png?resize=705%2C705&amp;ssl=1 705w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Need-help-with-your-CV_.png?resize=120%2C120&amp;ssl=1 120w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Need-help-with-your-CV_.png?resize=450%2C450&amp;ssl=1 450w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Need-help-with-your-CV_.png?resize=640%2C640&amp;ssl=1 640w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Need-help-with-your-CV_.png?resize=50%2C50&amp;ssl=1 50w, https://i1.wp.com/soleentrepreneur.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Need-help-with-your-CV_.png?w=800&amp;ssl=1 800w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px\" data-recalc-dims=\"1\" /></p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n';
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          SelectableText(
            _parseString('$string'),
          ),
          Text(_parseEmailString('$string'))
        ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out using wrong regex Regular Expression was

```
r"[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+"
```